# How to support syntax like `a && b = c` for a conditional assignment expression?

Tags: parsing, expressions, grammar

I want the expression `a && b = c` in my language to mean that the value of `c` is assigned to `b` when `a` is true, and nothing is done otherwise. In other words, the `&&` operator short-circuits, and the expression `b = c` on the right-hand side is evaluated only when the left-hand side is true.

How can I define and implement this grammar rule in a programming language?

Comment: Just give `&&` and `=` the same level of priority, but right-associative, so that `a && b = c` is parsed as `a && (b = c)` and `a = b && c` is parsed as `a = (b && c)`

Comment: C's operator precedence says that && binds tighter than =.  Thus, your expression is the same as (a&&b)=c, which doesn't work.  To fix, simply add ()'s where needed, e.g. a&&(b=c).

Comment: @ErikEidt I see. I went through the expressions chapter again and see that the right side of logical-AND-expr don't accept a non-terminal 'expression' term unless it's bracketted in `()` as specified in primary-expression.

Comment: In short, in C, we parse that as `(a&&b)=c`, which is valid (and recognizable) syntax yet later a semantic error b/c assignment requires something assignable.  This is not something to be fixed by parsing, since something assignable can be an expression of considerable complexity.

Comment: The title of this question is incorrect and confusing, because "successfully parse the expression `a && b = c` in C" means "parse `a && b = c` as meaning `(a && b) = c`." If your question is "How can we parse a && b = c as meaning 'if a is true, set b to c' in a C-like language?" then that's what the title should say.

Comment: Technically, assigning meaning to this expression is not done in the parser; the parser only figures out the lexical structure (i.e. it's an `&&` operator with a simple name `a` on the left, and a `=` operator on the right with simple names `b` and `c` for its left and right sides).

Comment: I tried to rewrite the question to get at the part of the core idea that would be on topic for this site. Asking about what's allowed in C is a question for Stack Overflow; and asking about whether a C behaviour is caused by "the grammar" or "the compiler" makes no sense **because there are many possible compilers**. Of course it's the grammar, unless there's an actual bug in the compiler; if every compiler works the same way then surely it isn't a bug. If you don't know, then doing the testing is your responsibility. **If you do find a compiler bug, file a bug report** instead of asking here.

Comment: Personally that is less readable than just `if(a) b = c;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert, so feel free to correct me if I've missed something fundamental here, but looking at [the Bison parser for PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y), the way it is resolved there is not related to *precedence*, but to the productions defined.

Specifically, most binary operators (including `&&`) are defined as accepting any expression on the left-hand side; but *assignment* is defined as accepting a smaller set of syntax on the left-hand side.

In PHP's case, the token allowed on the left is called `variable`, but it might more generally be called an `lvalue`. The key limitations are:

- You need to distinguish in the grammar between "assignment operators" and other "binary operators". This may make a difference in a language with liberal operator overloading.
- You need to define in the grammar some subset of expressions which *may* be valid "lvalues". This can still include cases which fail at a later compiler phase, or even at run-time. It can even include `'(' expression ')'` so that `(a && b) = c` compiles, but means something different from `a && b = c`.

In the case of PHP:

- PHP does not allow operator overloading or custom operators, but does define combined assignment operators such as `+=`; these are handled with similar rules.
- It also has array destructuring (`[$a, $b] = $array`) which is handled as an additional rule for `=` only.
- The `variable` rule includes not just `$foo` but also other variable-like things, such as `$object->property` and `SomeClass::$staticProperty`.
- In fact, it also includes things which can't be assigned to, because of how it's reused in other parts of the parser: `foo() = 42;` gives a compilation error, but not a parser error.
- However, crucially, it *doesn't* include anything that matches `$a && $b`.

Here's an edited excerpt of PHP's Bison rules (without the target code which generates AST nodes):

```
expr:
        variable
    |   '[' array_pair_list ']' '=' expr
    |   variable '=' expr
    |   variable T_PLUS_EQUAL expr
    |   expr T_BOOLEAN_AND expr

variable:
        simple_variable
    |   static_member
    |   array_object_dereferenceable T_OBJECT_OPERATOR property_name
    |   array_object_dereferenceable T_NULLSAFE_OBJECT_OPERATOR property_name
```

Let's examine a simplified version with just assignment and logical and:

```
expression: variable | assignment | and_expression
assignment: variable '=' expression
and_expression: expression '&&' expression
```

Given the input `$a && $b = $c`, the stack will proceed as follows

- `$a` - shift - `variable`
- `&&` - reduce, then shift - `expression '&&'`
- `$b` - shift - `expression '&&' variable`
- `=` - shift (because `and_expression '='` does not match any rule) - `expression '&&' variable '='`
- `$c` - shift - `expression '&&' variable '=' variable`
- reduce - `expression '&&' assignment`
- reduce - `expression '&&' expression`
- reduce - `and_expression`
- reduce - `expression`

The resulting AST is equivalent to `$a && ($b = $c)`

Comment: Interesting! This effectively builds a more tolerant parser; `$a && $b = $c` is parsed as `$a && ($b = $c)` because the parser knows that `($a && $b) = $c` wouldn't make sense. In C, `a && b = c` results in an error because it is parsed as `(a && b) = c` and then recognised as not making sense. And in some languages, PHP's rules would be a nightmare. Consider C++ and its overloading of operators. You wouldn't want the evaluation of `a && b = c` to depend on whether `&&` returns an lvalue or not. (Now I'm tempted to try to write a C++ program that compiles with `a && b = c`...)

Comment: @Stef Indeed, it relies on having a fairly conservative definition of "lvalue", and not treating `=` as a generic "operator" token. In PHP, it's just three very explicit rules: the basic `variable '=' expr` plus `T_LIST '(' array_pair_list ')' '=' expr` and `'[' array_pair_list ']' '=' expr` for two styles of array destructuring (`list($a, $b) = $array` and `[$a, $b] = $array`).

Comment: @Stef I guess if you wanted run-time lvalues, you could trade off by requiring parentheses around them - `lvalue = variable | '(' expr ')'` Then `($a && $b) = $c` would compile, and attempt to create an lvalue at run-time, but `$a && $b = $c` would still be equivalent to `$a && ($b = $c)`

Comment: If you had C's indirection operator, then `*p=5` would parse as `*(p=5)`.  And what of `a[i]=5` or `f()->g=5`?

Comment: @ErikEidt It would be no problem to include rules for all of those in the definition of "lvalue"; in fact, although PHP calls the rule "variable", it includes the equivalent of all of them - `$$p`, `$a[$]`, and `f()->g` would all be reduced as "variable" in the parser. I've edited my answer to make that clear, as well as incorporating my comment above about allowing `( expression )` as an lvalue.

Comment: PHP's array destructuring isn't only in assignment, you can also write `foreach ($array as [$v1, $v2])`

Comment: @Barmar Indeed; that's handled in a completely separate rule, `foreach_variable`: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L670 The two variants on both places all share an inner rule, `array_pair_list`

Answer (score 1):

PHP supports this:

```php
<?php
$a = true; $a && $b = 1; echo $b;
```

Output:

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLJVHBVqGkqDTVWgHIVFNTUEkCChhaK6QmZ@QDOdb//wMA)

Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) only says it is a special case in a note:

> Note: Although `=` has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: `if (!$a = foo())`, in which case the return value of `foo()` is put into `$a`.

But this could be done by using different left and right operator precedence, just like how you usually implement brackets, where it has a high precedence outside but low precedence inside.

If you use a formal grammar, the number of symbols seems to explode:

```
level5 = identifier | constant | "(" level0 ")"
level4 = level5
level3 = level3 ("*" | "/") level4 | level4
level2 = level2 ("+" | "-") level3 | level3
level1 = level2 | level2_1
level4_1 = level4 "=" level1
level3_1 = level3 ("*" | "/") level4_1 | level4_1
level2_1 = level2 ("+" | "-") level3_1 | level3_1
level0 = level0 ";" level1 | level1
```

This may conflict with the Python way of assigning multiple variables:

```python
a, b = 1, 2
```

Comment: Looking at [the PHP parser](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) there's no obvious explicit "special case" to make this assignment work. I don't understand parser theory well enough, but I think it may just be that there is a production `expr: variable '=' expr` but no `expr: expr '=' expr`, so `$a && $b = 1;` can't result in `expr(expr(variable '&&' variable) '=' scalar))`, it  has to be interpreted as `expr(variable '&&' expr(variable '=' scalar))`

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating from comments (credits goes to @Stef and @ErikEidt).

Q1: The parser doesn't help in this case. There are 3 ways out of it:

1. add the `expresion` non-terminal to the `primary-expression` non-terminal, (and this would yield an ambiguous grammar).
2. Give logical operators same precedance as assignment operators. This is a breaking change to all C programs (and any program written in one of the C-family language).
3. Borrow from Perl, use literal `and` and `or` for lower precedance.

Q2: that of the grammar.

Comment: To be fair it's a bit hard to understand what you're asking exactly. `a && b = c` is definitely an error in C, but doesn't have to be an error in another language. It's not a "failure" so much as a definition. The parser in a C compiler successfully parses `a && b = c` as `(a && b) = c`, which results in an error because `(a && b)` is an rvalue whereas `=` requires an lvalue on the left of `=`. You want `a && b = c` to be parsed as `a && (b = c)`, which is totally possible, just not C.

Comment: As an example of a different language making different choices: `a < b < c` is parsed as `(a < b) < c` in C, but as syntactic sugar for `(a < b) && (b < c)` in python.